# filtering on geo_distance in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to set a maximum distance from my center location in my elasticsearch query, there's no problems with the sorting part:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "sort"  : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "location" : "56,14",
                "order"    : "asc",
                "unit"     : "km"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

however when I try adding a filter I get the `"[geo_distance] filter does not support [location]"`:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query"  : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "200m",
                    "location" : {
                        "location" : "56,14"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort"  : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "location" : "56,14",
                "order"    : "asc",
                "unit"     : "km"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you try "localtion.location" according to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html#_lat_lon_as_string_4

Comment: the reason for them using pin.location is cause they saved the location in a sub veriable of pin, I have not saved my location in an sub like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this filter instead

```
 "filter" : {
        "geo_distance" : {
            "distance" : "200m",
            "location" : "56,14"
        }
    }
```

Location can be any name for the field like if you field name is loc or locator,then the query would be

```
"filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "200m",
                "loc"/"locator" : "56,14"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had totally missed that one!